# xpages save / cancel actions scenario

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I will describe shortly my little project application:

the main doc. content is `Cdoc` ( datasource which contains fields + a button ). This button displays a dialog which is `Pdoc` ( a datasource ) - before showing the button I will save the doc. to get the UNID and then I will pass it to the `Pdoc`, I want to link the `Cdoc` and `Pdoc` with the UNID.
My button which shows the dialog:

```
<xp:button value="Adding Pdoc from the dialog" id="button3"
        styleClass="lotusFormButton" refreshMode="partial">

        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="computedField3">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript: if ( Cdoc.isNewNote() ) { Cdoc.save(); }
Cdoc.setValue("computedField3",Cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalID());
getComponent('exampleDialog').show()}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
```

The dialog / `Pdoc` contains  just 1 button: `Save` ( because the `X` button is implicitly added to the dialog )

```
<xp:button value="Salvare" id="button6" styleClass="lotusFormButton">

<xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
    submit="true" refreshMode="partial" immediate="false"
    save="false" refreshId="viewPanel1">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:Pdoc.save();     
getComponent('exampleDialog').hide();
   }]]>
           </xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

So, it saves the docs. from `Pdoc` and they are displayed in an embedded view from `Cdoc`.

The main. doc `Cdoc` contains also 2 (actions) buttons:

```
Cancel: redirect to Previous Page.
```

and

```
Save
<xp:button value="Salvare" id="buttonSave" styleClass="lotusFormButton" rendered="#{javascript:currentDocument.isEditable()}">

            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                refreshMode="partial" immediate="false" save="true"
                id="eventHandler1">
                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (Cdoc.getItemValueString("txt_UNID")!= "") { 

Cdoc.save(); 
}
facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("http://ourserver.ro/XApp.nsf/view.xsp")

}]]></xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

The problem is:

Let say I'll create 3 docs. from `Pdoc` from the dialog, the Cdoc. is already saved ( because the UNID was obtained ). If I save then using `Cdoc` `Save,` my main view panel from `view.xsp` will display:

- one doc. `Cdoc` with its 3 `Pdoc` docs. ( I need just this case to be displayed )
- another `Cdoc` ( I guess when I first obtain the UNID and I saved the `Cdoc` to obtain the UNID, this is the `Cdoc` in this case.  Btw, if I save again `Cdoc` using the `Save` button , will the UNID will change ? ) and one empty ( don't know why ) `Pdoc` from the dialog.

How should my `Save` button from `Cdoc` should be like? Should I change also the `Save` from `Pdoc` button?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: My Cdoc: <xp:dominoDocument var="Cdoc" formName="fmCompanie"
   computeWithForm="both" ignoreRequestParams="true">

  </xp:dominoDocument>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe save="true" on a button will submit and save all datasources on the page. That could explain spurious Pdoc documents. You're calling the save in script, so you don't need save="true" - you can just use a normal Button type rather than Submit type for the button.

Once a Document has been saved, the UNID will not be changed.

Comment: Thanks it seems to be working now, one issue though regarding my button which shows the dialog: if I opened an existing CDoc ( already saved ) and then adding a new Pdoc ( from the dialog , using the button ) my computed text which contains the UNID is changing, when clicking the button. My button's code:  if ( Cdoc.isNewNote() ) { Cdoc.save(); }
Cdoc.setValue("computedField3",Cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalID());
getComponent('exampleDialog').show()

Comment: Is your Cdoc exactly as in the comment above? If so, you're setting ignoreRequestParams on Cdoc and not setting the documentId property at all. That means regardless of whether you're opening a document from a view or creating a new document, Cdoc will *always* be a new document. So it's no surprise that the UNID will change. I'd suggest reviewing dominoDocument datasources, possibly the section at the start of Chapter 7 of Mastering XPages 2nd Edition

Comment: I did ordered the Mastering XPages 2 months ago, this week I got a response that it will arrive this week. I'm still waiting it. So, should I put the ignoreRequestParams to false? My button code is:  if ( Cdoc.isNewNote() ) { Cdoc.save();
 Cdoc.setValue("computedField3",Cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalID());
 getComponent('exampleDialog').show() }
 else
 {
Cdoc.setValue("computedField3",Cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalID());
getComponent('exampleDialog').show()}.

Comment: Yes, use the default of ignoreRequestParams="false". Good luck with Mastering XPages. It looks daunting because of its size, but it's full on great content.