# xpages UNID of documents / why it is changing

Tags: xpages

I'm trying to link 2 documents ( `Cdoc` and `Pdoc` ) based on the `Cdoc UNID`.

I have a computed field ( `computedfield3` ) which is binded to a form'computed field having the default value `@text(@documentuniqueid)`. The `Pdoc` is inside a dialog which I show it using a button.

The button contains a `Partial Update` for `ID:computedField3`.

The button code:

```
 if ( Cdoc.isNewNote() ) { Cdoc.save();
 Cdoc.setValue("computedField3",Cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalID());
 getComponent('exampleDialog').show() }
 else
 {
 Cdoc.setValue("computedField3",Cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalID());
 getComponent('exampleDialog').show()}
```

Then I pass the `computedField3` value to `Pdoc` using custom control properties.

I noticed if I opened an existing already saved `Cdoc`, open it and add again a `Pdoc` from the dialog, the existing UNID from the `Cdoc` is changing... Is from the partial update?

How can I make it OK ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is, you might be overwriting cdoc somewhere - please create a simple whole example with the problem so we can help you better. Also please note that UniversalId is a read/write property, so make sure you are not changing it somewhere in your code by mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is not the save code. It's the dominoDocument datasource definition. Please see my latest comment here [xpages save / cancel actions scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400934/xpages-save-cancel-actions-scenario)

With ignoreRequestParams set to true and no documentId computed, you're always working on a new document.

Comment: Thank you @Paul. I remove the ignoreRequestParams, and also got the UNID computed. Now, it doesn't change it anymore when the doc. is already saved and reopened.

Comment: If ignoreRequestParams is false, you don't need to compute the UNID. It will always use whatever is in the URL and if there's nothing in the URL, use a new document. So the documentId property will get overwritten by the URL parameters. Computing the documentId is only relevant if ignoreRequestParams is true.

Comment: thanks. I read something that is important to set ignoreRequestParams to true when using two or more datasources ( in entire nsf. or let say inside a xpage / custom controls ? ). Well, now even I removed the property from true, I created a visible computed field where I pass the value: Cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalID() just to verify if everything is ok.