# xpages should I use ignorerequestParams set to true

Tags: xpages

based on these questions:

[xpages UNID of documents / why it is changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24407003/xpages-unid-of-documents-why-it-is-changing)

[xpages why my field value isn't copied correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758110/xpages-why-my-field-value-isnt-copied-correctly)

i noticed, unfortunately, some computed field which stores the UNID is changing if I hit refresh / F5.

my XPage has defined one datasource ( `Cdoc` ) and it contains a button which shows a dialog. this dialog has defined other datasource ( `Pdoc` ). The dialog contains several fields, which inherit some values from `Cdoc`...

Should I use `ignorerequestParams` property for one of these datasources? Can you explain the meaning of this property?

What happens:

The field which stores the UNID of the `Cdoc` after I show the dialog and create some `Pdoc` and list it in a `viewPanel` inside the XPage ( `Cdoc` datasource ) and then hit `F5` the `Cdoc UNID` is changing ... even if it is computed.

Also, if the doc. `isNewNote()` the url is something like this:

```
server/Test.nsf/doc.xsp?action=newDocument
```

even after I call `Cdoc.save()`. I think this could be a reason why the computedField which stores the UNID is changing when I hit refresh => a newDoc is created.

Meanwhile, I put the `ignoreRequestParams` set to `true` just for the dialog ( `Pdoc` ).

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

By default, the UNID and action (open, create, edit) are defined by the URL query string,  i.e. the request parameters. With requestParamPrefix you can define which entry in the query string is used to find the document parameters for *this* datasource. By default  that's documentId. But if you want to manage the UNID and action yourself through code, that's when you need to set ignoreRequestParams="true".

If you have two datasources on a page, you will need to use either ignoreRequestParams or requestParamPrefix on one of them. If not, you're editing the same document in both datasources.

Comment: so it's ok to put the ignoreRequestParams="true" only for the dialog? I don't have two datasources on a page.

Comment: I dont think I understood your answer ( my fault, I'm newbie in XPages development ), that is the reason I put my scenario in the question, considering I having some difficulties understanding some generals concepts.

Comment: @MFGFlay it is quite easy, in fact: request params in URL "override" undefined properties of datasource by default. Property ignoreRequestParams turns this behavior off completely for that datasource. Property requestParamPrefix will "listen to" different - prefixed parameters in URL.

Comment: You say you have two datasources, CDoc and PDoc. Are these trying to be two different Notes documents or the same Notes document. It sounds like the latter.

Comment: @PaulStephenWithers : Cdoc and Pdoc are trying to act as two different documents. Cdoc has, also, a view panel where lists all the Pdoc docs. The Pdocs are created from the Cdoc / xpages by showing a dialog ( the dialog itself is Pdoc )

Comment: The partial refresh won't change the URL, so you're right that refreshing the page creates another new document. An alternative is in the save button to do context.redirectToPage("doc.xsp?documentId="+CDoc.getUniversalID()). Add &action=editDocument if you want it in edit mode, assuming the default is openDocument. For the documentId query string parameter, you can also use the note id as well as the UNID.